# Do shops need permission to produce scale/action figurines based on anime/manga characters?

Tags: anime-production

Like, for example, does [Good Smile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Smile_Company) need permission from the mangaka to create a bunny version of an anime/manga character he/she created or can they just do it either way and sell it straight up?

Comment: I suppose yes. I don't see why they would not need such permission considering it would be used for commercial purpose.